# question on gluing many 1 x 1 squares to form a rectangle

Tags: coloring

"You have many 1 x 1 unit squares. You may colour the edges with one of four colours and glue them together along edges of the same colour. Your aim is to get an m x n rectangle. For what value of m and n is it possible?"

I have the above question with me. Trying out a few squares is it not possible for any such m and n. I guess so!! Like I can take any two squares and glue them along the same colours and attach one more square having the required edge colour and glue it?

Comment: Something seems to be missing from the question. Can you not colour all the edges of the squares the same colour, and then glue the squares together in a rectangle as large as you want?

Comment: It is not clear what the constraints are.
Can you rotate the squares? can you flip them? Are you allowed to color each square individually or you are required to color all squares in same manner? Let's say you are required to color all squares in same manner and you are not allowed to rotate/flip the square, then you can't even glue two squares into a $1 \times 2$ rectangle.

Comment: yupp no such constraints given. The problem is from the book "Problem Solving Strategies" by Arthur Engel, page 27 question number 21

Comment: A variant of the same question is also there in the above mentioned book, question number 22, wherein the same arrangement is extended to 3 dimension, squares replaced by cubes

Comment: The question is indeed as quoted from the book, but it is missing information. From reading the answer, it seems that the squares need to have four differently coloured edges, and furthermore, the finished rectangle must also have four differently coloured sides (and each rectangle side is just one colour). None of this is stated in the question. The followup cube question at least states that each cube has six colours and that the final faces should all have a different colour.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Can you help me prove the case of the cube?

Comment: You can build a cuboid with all odd dimensions, using the same method as the squares. So you have the odd/odd/odd case. You can extend this to even/even/odd, by adding a layer on two sides, swapping the outer face colours. You can also make even/even/even by extending odd/odd/odd on three sides, cyclically permuting the outer face colours. Lastly, the odd/odd/even case can be proved impossible in the same way as in the squares case - the colour on the odd/odd face would have to occur an odd number of times even though there are an even number of cubes.